# C# The best practice of telling the Task to Perform some action

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a shell for my BIG APP *(The BIG APP is just a Task for the shell)*. And I want somehow to tell the BIG APP to update it's settings from file at some point of it's operatioin.

It's Task is designed to run for days without restarting and I want the APP to have no references to the shell.
So the question is mentioned and here it is again: what is the best practice in such a case to tell the APP to do something?

No references to the shell is mandatory for me.

Comment: What is "The Shell"? Do you mean Explorer? And why not run the task as a Windows service? That's the best way to have long running activities in Windows.

Comment: No. The BUG APP stands for a main business-logic program with no UI (.dll project). And the shell is another C# projest within the sollution. But shell is just launches the business-logic app and displays it's state, cancels if needed, etc.

Comment: You could just use a `FileWatcher` and monitor the settings file for changes, reload when detected.

Comment: I know I can do that, but it's not the behaviour I'm looking for. Update has to be activated from the shell.

Comment: So have the shell call the "big app".Settings.Update() method or something like that. Without seeing how your "big app" is structured, its hard to tell you how to signal it.

Comment: Ron, thanks a lot. That task was too simple for Friday evening to deal with. So I missed obvious way.
Now everything works just fine.